# SharpRepository - Join Between Two Repositories

Tags: c#, linq, sharp-repository

I have scoured the net and was unable to find any example of conducting a join between two SharpRepository repos.  Can anyone provide a link to a page or an example?  I am attempting to conver the following linq expression into a sharp repo expression:

```
        var user = (from f in _context.AccountUsers
                    join h in _context.Users on f.UserId equals h.UserId
                    where f.AccountId == accountId && h.UserName.Contains(email)
                    select new
                    {
                        h
                    });
        return (IEnumerable<User>)user;
```

**----- UPDATE ------**

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't seem to be working propertly...

```
            var aur = new AccountUserRepository();
        var user = this.Join(aur, u => u.UserName.Contains(email), au => au.AccountId == accountId, 
            (u, au)=> u).AsQueryable().AsEnumerable();
        return user;
```

Comment: btw - the this in the sharprepo version is the UserAccuont (User) repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Join method on the repository that is similar to a LINQ Join statement and will let you join one IRepository<> with another IRepository<>.  You pass it an IRepository<> to join with, an inner key selector, an outer key selector and a result selector.

You can look here for an integration test that uses it: https://github.com/SharpRepository/SharpRepository/blob/master/SharpRepository.Tests.Integration/RepositoryJoinTests.cs

The result of this call is another repository that you can then call GetAll, or FindAll, etc. on just like it was a normal IRepository<> itself.  So I think you'll want to do something like this:

```
var accountUserRepo = new AccountUserRepository();
var userRepo = new UserRepository();

// join on the UserId column that is common to both, and select an anonymous type with both pieces of info (you would select just what you need)
var compositeRepo = accountUserRepo.Join(userRepo, au => au.UserId, u => u.UserId, (au, u) => new { AccountUserInfo = au, UserInfo = u } );

return compositeRepo.FindAll(x => UserInfo.UserName.Contains(email) && x.AccountInfo.AccountId == accountId, x => x.UserInfo);
```

That is how I think you would do it with the Join syntax.

If you have navigation properties like you would in EF you could probably just do this syntax which is simpler:

```
return accountUserRepo.FindAll(x => x.AccountId == accountId && x.User.UserName.Contains(email), x => x.User);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, didn't realize it returned another repo!

Comment: Yeah I think we could make the documentation a bit better on that.  I'll make a note to do that.

Comment: Jeff can you explain how to do outer join?

Comment: Unfortunately, for an outer join you will need to break out of the repository and get a IQueryable and do it as you normally would against LINQ.  You can call userRepo.AsQueryable() to get the underlying queryable that you can then use as you normally would.  Keep in mind, that when you do this you won't get the benefits of caching, or any aspects/hooks you might have on the repository itself.